# only my first route is being recognized why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

app.js

I have imported each and every thing but it is only recognizing the first line in routers tag. If I put the home before it will show home and ignore header.

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import Home from './Home';
import{BrowserRouter as Router, Routes,  Route,Link} from "react-router-dom";
 

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="App">
    

      <Routes >
          {/*Header */}
          
          <Route path="/" element={<Header /> } />
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
         
          
          
          
         
          {/*Home */}
          
          
      </Routes>
      
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: try using exact attribute with your first route and you may check one example from here

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/basic

Comment: How would you imagine this to work with two routes with the same `path`?

Comment: @NoumanAhmad V5 doesn't have `<Routes>`, this is v6.

Comment: I think you want to show two component in one route so you need to wrap both component in one component it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

try with exact  keyword like `<Route exact path="/" element={< Home />} />` And don't put both component in one Path. Here's full code

```
<Router>
<Header />
<Routes >
          <Route exact  path="/" element={<Home />} /> 
      </Routes>
</Router>
```